# Marshal string to asciiz

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm trying to invoke a DLL function that requires Asciiz pointers:

```
int doExample(Asciiz* FolderPath, Asciiz* OutputPath, int Flags);
```

I've tried using `StringBuilder`, but I keep getting errors about accessing protected memory. This is my C# code:

```
public class Example
{
  [DllImport("Example.dll", EntryPoint="?doExample@Example@@QADHPYDH0P6A_N0ZZ000@Z")]
        static extern int doExample(StringBuilder folderPath, StringBuilder outputPath, int flags);

  public int do(string folderPath, string outputPath)
  {
    StringBuilder FolderPath = new StringBuilder(folderPath);
    StringBuilder OutputPath = new StringBuilder(outputPath);
    doExample(FolderPath, OutputPath, 0);
  }
}
```

Any ideas as to why this would be happening? Or would this strictly be an error in the C++ code?

Edit: based on the comments, here is so more info:

- The DLL is built on VS2010
- I am building the C# code in VS2012 (could the difference here be causing an issue?)
- I don't know exactly what the function in the DLL does; my knowledge in C++ is very limited. Basicly, it gets a directory, compresses it and outputs it to the outputpath in a single file.
- I know the name mangling in the EntryPoint is incorrect; I've put some random characters in; the function name is not the same as it is in the actual DLL, but argument types and return type is the same. Also, I got the real mangled function name from Dependency Walker. If I didn't specify the EntryPoint, it couldn't find the function. (I do have the C++ source code btw of this DLL)
- The full error is: AccessViolationException was unhandled: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: That function name is not one that the MSVC++ compiler could generate although the name mangling is pretty similar.  You have to be specific about the native compiler you use.  The missing CallingConvention is notable, almost always Cdecl for C++ functions.  Non-static instance methods cannot be pinvoked.

Comment: How is `Asciiz` defined? What is the calling convention of your function? Why can't we see the error message? Is the function really modifying both strings?

Comment: I have specified more information in the question now.

Comment: You did not answer all the questions. How is Asciiz defined? What is the calling convention of your function? Is the function really modifying both strings? And a new one. What is the true mangled name? If you told us that we could decode it into a signature! That would help you! We can certainly help you, but you've got to give more information.